# Missing period in DHCP domain search

Tags: domain-name-system, networkmanager

On my server running the ISC DHCP daemon, I have the following in `/etc/dhcpd.conf`:

```
...
option domain-name "example.com";
option domain-search "example.com";
...
```

On my clients running the latest version of Network Manager, I'm seeing the following in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search examplecom
...
```

This obviously prevents the search from working correctly.  This just started happening recently, I think after updating to Network Manager 1.22.0-1.  Is this a known bug in the latest version, or is there something else I need to look at in my configuration?

Comment: I wonder if you need to escape a special character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with 1.22.0 on ArchLinux: all periods were removed from the search domains. I now updated to 1.22.2 and the problem went away.

The [release notes for 1.22.2](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/f207472dfad6a567d0e27dd5cae6d1f8613c49e0/NEWS) include this:

> Fix multiple issues in the internal DHCP client, including wrong
>     parsing of search domains and classless routes options, and failures
>     in obtaining and renewing the lease with certain server
>     configurations.

So the bug has been fixed \o/